# Allow multi-line in EditText view in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline

How to allow multi-line in Android's `EditText` view?

Answer (score 1370, accepted):

By default all the `EditText` widgets in Android are multi-lined.

Here is some sample code:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" <!-- Multiline input -->
    android:lines="8" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
    android:minLines="6" <!-- Minimum lines -->
    android:gravity="top|start" <!-- Cursor Position -->
    android:maxLines="10" <!-- Maximum Lines -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Height determined by content -->
    android:layout_width="match_parent" <!-- Fill entire width -->
    android:scrollbars="vertical" <!-- Vertical Scroll Bar -->
/>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have inputType set to textMultiLine and imeOptions to actionSend? I see an Enter key on the S4 keyboard instead of send when I set inputType to textMultiLine and imeOptions to actionSend.

Comment: For "textMultiLine and imeOptions" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014219/multiline-edittext-with-done-softinput-action-label-on-2-3

Comment: One thing to note, adding an `inputType` negates at least the `lines` and `minLines` attributes. I had `inputType="phone"` and the lines attributes had no effect

Comment: Do not use this. Causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as soon as you type something because of `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

Comment: if using AppCompactTextView need this line  
     android:inputType="textMultiLine"

Comment: Programmatically: ```txt.setSingleLine(false);
txt.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);```

Answer (score 326):

You may find it better to use:

```
<EditText 
...
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
/>
```

This is because `android:singleLine` is deprecated.

Comment: Sharduls answer should certainly work on modern Apis. Since they removed the deprecated `singleLine` part of their answer (a long time ago). Regarding the question itself, that is the most important part of their answer.

Comment: Do not use this. Causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as soon as you type something. Multiline now is the default.

Comment: @Chisko An XML attribute wouldn't cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException. I can't remember when the default inputType changed (did it even?), but it is probably best to keep this in for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: @Knossos well, as strange as it is for you it is for me. I literally copy-pasted the code and crashed every time with every possible combination of several parameters until I removed that. Go figure.

Answer (score 48):

This works for me, actually these 2 attributes are important: **inputType** and **lines**. Besides, you may need a scrollbar, the code below shows how to make one:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addr_edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textMultiLine"
        android:lines="20"
        android:minLines="5"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 30):

This is how I applied the code snippet below and it's working fine. Hope, this would help somebody.

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android:gravity="top|left" 
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:lines="5" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" 
/>
```

Cheers! ...Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

EditText has **singleLine** property. You can set in the XML or by calling setSingleLine(false);
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSingleLine%28%29

Answer (score 11):

Try this,
add these lines to your edit text view, i'll add mine. make sure you understand it

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical"

<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText_newprom_description"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:lines="5"
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:minLines="5"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

and on your java class make on click listner to this edit text as follows, i'll add mine, chane names according to yours.

```
EditText description;
description = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_newprom_description);

description.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }

        });
```

this works fine for me

Comment: Thanks you! This is how I made an edit text scrollable within a scrollable view.

Answer (score 7):

if some one is using **AppCompatEditText** then you need to set **inputType="textMultiLine"** here is the code you can copy

---

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:id="@+id/etNote"
        android:minLines="6"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:lines="8"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:autofillHints=""

        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         />
```

for background

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape android:shape="rectangle" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <corners android:radius="@dimen/_5sdp"/>
   <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#C8C8C8"/>
   </shape>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

This code line work for me.  Add this code you edittext in your xml file.

Answer (score 6):

Just add this 
 `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` 
in XML file on relevant field.

Answer (score 5):

All of these are nice but will not work in case you have your edittext inside upper level scroll view :) Perhaps most common example is "Settings" view that has so many items that the they go beyond of visible area. In this case you put them all into scroll view to make settings scrollable. In case that you need multiline scrollable edit text in your settings, its scroll will not work.

Answer (score 5):

To disable number of lines that was previously assigned in theme use xml attribute: `android:lines="@null"`

Answer (score 5):

```
 <EditText
           android:id="@id/editText" //id of editText
           android:gravity="start"   // Where to start Typing
           android:inputType="textMultiLine" // multiline
           android:imeOptions="actionDone" // Keyboard done button
           android:minLines="5" // Min Line of editText
           android:hint="@string/Enter Data" // Hint in editText
           android:layout_width="match_parent" //width editText
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" //height editText
           />
```

Answer (score 3):

I learned this from http://www.pcsalt.com/android/edittext-with-single-line-line-wrapping-and-done-action-in-android/, though I don't like the website myself. If you want multiline BUT want to retain the enter button as a post button, set the listview's "horizontally scrolling" to false.

`android:scrollHorizontally="false"`

If it doesn't work in xml, doing it programmatically weirdly works.

`listView.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Another neat thing to do is to use `android:minHeight` along with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. This way you can set the size of the edit when it's empty, and when the user inputs stuff, it stretches according to how much the user inputs, including multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText
                android:hint="Address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                android:id="@+id/edittxtAddress"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/textsize2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:minLines="2"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
```

and in Activity to remove "\n" is user press nextline

```
String editStr= edittxtAddress.getText().toString().trim();

 MyString= editStr.replaceAll("\n"," ");
```