# Show keyboard programatically on Android with an OK/DONE button

Tags: java, android, input

I am trying to show the soft keyboard on a custom manually coded text field.  I use the following code and I get the standard keyboard with a return character at the bottom right.

```
inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

I would like to display the keyboard that has the OK (or perhaps it's DONE) in the bottom right.  When I did some research I found that the inputType can be set on the EditText (which I'm not using in this case), but not for the view i'm using (GLSurfaceView).

Any ideas how I can get the alternative keyboard showing?

**EDIT** I tried the solution posted here: - [Multiline EditText with Done SoftInput Action Label on 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014219/multiline-edittext-with-done-softinput-action-label-on-2-3) but unfortunately it didn't show the DONE button (I am on Android 2.1).  I tried changing the inputType field and that **did** change the type (i tried "phone"), but not the DONE button.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to obtain Done button on soft keyboard, you should set the "Ime options" of EditText field to actionDone

```
<EditText android:text="EditText" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

Comment: Thanks woodshy, but I'm not using EditText in this case, I am rendering the text directly in OpenGL

Comment: try also adding `android:singleLine="true"`