# Multiline EditText with IMEOption DONE or NEXT not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline

I am trying to view Keyboard with Next Button on Multiline Edit text. But it is not working for me.

Comment: how is it "not working"? what does it do if you press Next? and some code please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline EditText with Done SoftInput Action Label on 2.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014219/multiline-edittext-with-done-softinput-action-label-on-2-3)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set an IME Action on a multi-line edit text since the keyboard button that would be used for the next/done/search/... action is bound to be a ENTER/RETURN button to insert a line break.

Comment: Not true. The Google keep app does this somehow.

Comment: Anyone figure this out yet? I'm running into this very issue. I have a multiline field and I need a actionDone button.

Answer (score 0):

Fear not, it can be done. Though the following code works perfectly, but unfortunately I don't remember where I got the code from exactly and so cannot give the author the credit he/she so deserves.

```
////////////Code to Hide SoftKeyboard on Enter (DONE) Press///////////////
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
editText.setImeActionLabel("DONE",EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);              //Set Return Carriage as "DONE"
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) 
    {
                if (event == null) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                        // Capture soft enters in a singleLine EditText that is the last EditText
                        // This one is useful for the new list case, when there are no existing ListItems
                        editText.clearFocus();
                        //hide SoftKeyboard
                        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }

                    else if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                        // Capture soft enters in other singleLine EditTexts
                    } else if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                    } else {
                        // Let the system handle all other null KeyEvents
                        return false;
                    }
                } 
        else if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    // Capture most soft enters in multi-line EditTexts and all hard enters;
                    // They supply a zero actionId and a valid keyEvent rather than
                    // a non-zero actionId and a null event like the previous cases.
                    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        // We capture the event when the key is first pressed.
                    } else {
                        // We consume the event when the key is released.
                        return true;
                    }
                } 
        else {
                    // We let the system handle it when the listener is triggered by something that
                    // wasn't an enter.
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
        }
});
```

For passing the focus on to the **Next** EditText use `edit_text2.requestFocus()` and remove the Hide SoftKeyboard code.