# Multiline EditText with IMEOption Next in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method

I need to have a multiline EditText with Next button in keypad. When I set inputType to multiline, Next button doesn't appear on the keypad. I also tried setting imeOptions to actionNext but it doesn't work. I can see it working in the compose screen in Gmail app. It supports multiline EditText with Next button. How can I achieve it in my app?

Comment: i cant see next button in gmail app compose screen. Which phone and which gmail app version are you using?

Comment: I am using Nexus 4 (Jellybean). You can see Next button in the subject field in Gmail's compose screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline EditText with Done SoftInput Action Label on 2.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014219/multiline-edittext-with-done-softinput-action-label-on-2-3)