# How to limit the input characters of editText for the user and however being able to add disallowed characters programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, digits

Is it possible to limit the user to type only some characters on the keyboard. However, I should be able to add any disallowed character programmatically.

For instance, The user will be allowed to type only the following digits 'A','B' and 'C'.
This can be done from the xml code as follows:

```
< EditText
    ...
    android:digits="ABC" />
```

However, I want to be able to add a number in that EditText programmatically. Is this possible in Android?

Comment: _I want to be able to add a number in that EditText programmatically_. Why not `android:digits="ABC123"`? It should work.

Comment: Might [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45454342/3290339) help?...

Comment: @Abhi I don't wanna allow the user to type the numbers. That's why I am not adding them to the allowed digits

Comment: @Onik Well, it doesn't answer literally my question. It's mostly a workaround for that. But I've found there something that could help. It seems like there's no way in the Android to handle this case apart from listening to the changes and behaving correspondingly. Thank's for your answer