# how do i create a multiline string in EditText?

Tags: android, string, text, multiline

i want to display a string in a multiline EditText. Currently, the string displays as....

```
Receive: 0 coin(s) Total
             Cost: $100
```

I want want it to display as...

```
Receive: 0 coin(s) 
Total Cost: $10
```

This is my code, I have tried to use "\n", but to no avail...

```
result.setText("Receive:"+ " "+ df.format(rawounces)+"coin(s)" + "\n" 
     + "Total Cost:$" + df.format(transactionandpremium*rawounces));
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use to different text view for receive and total cost!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow multiline in EditText view in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233626/allow-multiline-in-edittext-view-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the   `android:minLines="3"` for display the multiline in edittext.
and for display cursor on the top of the edittext you can use like `android:gravity="top."`

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:minLines="3"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Comment: I would give the similar answer..+1