# How do i start a new line in String?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, settext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do i create a multiline string in EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642550/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-string-in-edittext)

i want to display a string in a multiline EditText. Currently, the string displays as....

```
Receive: 0 coin(s) Total
             Cost: $100
```

I want want it to display as...

```
Receive: 0 coin(s) 
Total Cost: $10
```

This is my code, I have tried to use "\n", but to no avail...

```
result.setText("Receive:"+ " "+ df.format(rawounces)+"coin(s)" + "\n" 
     + "Total Cost:$" + df.format(transactionandpremium*rawounces));
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Double thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642550/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-string-in-edittext

Comment: Go on to delete any one of them.Don't waste the Resource.

Comment: Just 20 mins before asked the same question by same user. U could have edit the same question. Why did u asked it again with a different title... [Should be closed one]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Html attribute to set text as you want as ::

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

String str="Receive: 0 coin(s) <br> Total Cost: $10";
editText.setText(Html.formHtml(str));
```