# Robotium new line in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, robotium

is it possible to make a line break in an EditText by using Robotium?

I tried

```
solo.clickOnView(et);
solo.(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

as well as

```
solo.typeText(et, "\n");
```

Both are not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please make sure your EditText support multiple lines.

Then I found that for my cases, inputing multiple lines works for me when I use EnterText instead of TypeText.

e.g.

```
solo.EnterText(et, "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your EditText support line breaks normally? You may have to set

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

in the XML for your editText.

(Also see: [Allow multi-line in EditText view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233626/allow-multiline-in-edittext-view-in-android))

Comment: If I manually test the application, I can press Enter on my Software keyboard and it works. The automatic test should do the same