# Android - multiple email addresses as input

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android app and need to email to various users.
Currently I have an 'EditText' which is configured as:

`android:inputType="textEmailAddress"`

Once a button is pressed an email is sent to the address specified in this field.
But I would to create a multi address input list.
Is there a way to do it without change the 'EditText' to multiple lines and parsing the string myself?

Googled it but could not find a solution.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `lines` and `minLines` attribute in EditText.  Example would be:

```
<EditText
     android:inputType="textEmailAddress" <!-- email address -->
     android:lines="8" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
     android:minLines="6" <!-- Minimum lines -->
</EditText>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233626/allow-multi-line-in-edittext-view-in-android) for further details.

Comment: Thank you! Never thought of using the lines option.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a separator to separate the emails:
`first_email@gmail.com, second_email@gmail.com` and so on. In your code call `split()` method to get an array of emails from this long line.