# Text gets shifted to left i.e goes out of the screen on left side when i start to enter text in the `EditText`

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I am trying to use an `EditText` in my app.I have used `match_parent` for the `EditText` .When i try to enter some  text in that EditText then it gets shifted to left and henceforth the earlier text goes out of screen.All of this is done inside a `scrollview`.

I want that all the text written should be visible on the screen.
Here is `activity_main.xml`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"  >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4233683/2504962) solution

Comment: I have edited the question.please see for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow multi-line in EditText view in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233626/allow-multi-line-in-edittext-view-in-android)

Comment: the layout_width of your ScrollView should be ``match_parent``. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

include `android:singleLine="true"` attribute in `EditText`

Hope that helps.

Comment: @ Mustansar Saeed, it's not working.Same problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this :

```
android:inputType="text"
```

to this :

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of you ScrollView to `match_parent`. If you want to your `EditText` to be multiline, just add `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`. Here's some sample code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
</ScrollView>
```