# How to set long text inside editext in such a way that it must display the end of the text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

i m creating a browser for my self.so when i set text of edittext by passing the  url of some link it shows only the beginning of the url.Ex- if the url is

https://stackoverflow.com/howtocreateabutton/

but the edittext shows only

https://stackoverflow.com/how

beacuse of overflow from the screen but i want to display the last of the link like -

com/howtocreateabutton/

Xml Code for Edittext:

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:onClick="enterAgain"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:inputType="textUri"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="Enter URL..."
    android:autoText="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textColorHighlight="#4384d4"
    android:textColor="#c1bfbf"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="right"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:id="@+id/edit_url"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
```

....help me guys...;(

Comment: i think there is something wrong with your edit text cuz the default behaviour is the way you wish. put your edit text code in your question

Comment: Default behaviour of edittext is scrollHorizontally true in case if u entering text but I am setting text i.e url so I think maybe its beacause of this setting text.....

Comment: you mean you are setting text pragmatically ?

Comment: Yes....I am getting the url from Webview then seeting it to the edittext....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it as following:

```
et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
```

i tested and it worked for me if anything went wrong put let me know in the comments

Comment: i am using et.setSelection(0,et.gettext().length());  to select whole url inside edittext..selection of this url is must .....but the problem is dat during selection edittext displaying url from start i.e from http;// but i want to display the end part of url....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only the end of text in edittext add this to your edittext xml

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Update see if this answer can help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233683/3868511

Comment: Nope...same for u my pal...I want to set whole of my url in edit text.... Not just last part...

Comment: i think there is something wrong with your edit text cuz the default behaviour is the way you wish. put your edit text code in your question – Amir Ziarati

Answer (score 0):

First get your editText data in String and split it into two parts so that you can display the last part of your code.

Comment: Not a solution for which I m looking for....I want to set whole url...so anybody can edit the who url...ur solution is not providing me this functionality