# App which displays List does not work

Tags: java, android

I try to make an App with button which after the push will display all elements from list in editText. 
But I have a problem, currently after I push the button I see only "second" in `editText`
In my opinion I need a tips from you about how to do it.  Maybe I shouldn't use a loop ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private EditText editText;
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        list.add(0, "first");
        list.add(1, "second");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (String abc: list){

                    editText.setText(abc);

                }


            }
        });
    }

}
```

____ edit

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private EditText editText;
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        list.add(0, "first");
        list.add(1, "second");
        list.add(2, "3");
        list.add(3, "4");
        list.add(4, "5");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String final_text = "";

                for (String abc: list){

                    final_text = final_text + "\n" + abc;

                }

                editText.setText(final_text);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5sVE.png)

Comment: Hint: You are overwriting `"first"` with "`second"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the text in `editText`. Accumulate the strings from the `list` and do a `setText` outside the loop:-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  String final_text ="";
  for (String abc: list){
   final_text = final_text +"\n" + abc;
  }
  editText.setText(final_text);
}
```

Comment: single words are still in this same lane

Comment: every list element should be in a new line due to `final_text +"\n" + abc`

Comment: i added edit question with screen and finally new code, how does it look on device, can you check why didn't work ?

Comment: make sure your editText's property in manifest.xml is set to multi-line : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233626/allow-multi-line-in-edittext-view-in-android

Comment: wow, nice, and last question, is it possible to do it without 1st emply line ?

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Do you mind accepting-upvoting the ans.. 
There is no "1st empty line" in your picture - it's the way the layout is drawn - probably top padding and / or middle placement ..

Comment: stack don't let me upvote answer because i don't have 15 reputation :/

Answer (score 0):

On this loop you will always get the last string of the list into the edittext

```
for (String abc: list){
    editText.setText(abc);
}
```

You need to create multiple edittext to add multiple value from your list, or else you need to compile all value from list to one string like @Zakir has propose.