# How to take paragraphs as an input in android?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-layout

I am developing a Notes app and I want to implement a kind of text area thing where user can enter as many paragraphs as he wants and then all of that gets saved in the database.
Edit texts look good when you want to take short input like name and phone number but what to do in this case ?

Something like this :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edittext has one more propery.. Multiline, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233626/allow-multi-line-in-edittext-view-in-android

Comment: @VivekGupta Thank you so much, I've attached some pictures in question I want something like that can you explain me for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is in React native try this props :

```
 <TextInput 
  multiline={true}
  />
```

Then if its in android try this :

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

as vivek suggested.

Hope it helps, feel free for doubts

Comment: Thank you so much, I've attached some pictures in question I want something like that

Comment: yes this can be done, with the above, entire thing to be one text edit

Comment: glad it helped, do upvote if you felt the answer was correct :)