# EditText with maxLines - how to show half of top line

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my layout there is `EditText` with `android:maxLines="4"`.
And when text exceeds 4 lines, strongly last 4 lines are shown in `EditText`.
This is by design.
[image]

But how can I show 4 and **half** lines? Like this
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233626/allow-multi-line-in-edittext-view-in-android

Comment: Not about I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

After short have found solution. Just add to layout

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_max="87dp"
```

You should be find suitable value of the attribute experimentally, depending on `maxLines` and `fontSize` in your case.